# ido freezes when a non-existent file match is entered

Tags: emacs, ido

Sometimes when I enter a non-existent file match in ido, by mistake, it freezes.... is there an option I can turn off.... it works really well the rest of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give us any background - such as OS, Emacs version, etc. However you may try my [ido config](http://gist.github.com/370166) - it works great for me. I'm using the ido that ships with Emacs 23.

Comment: I have those settings and a few others.... I tried using just yours but I still get problems.... Its good to know that yours work....  Are you using cygwin, and the cygwin-mount.el.... I am using the latest patched EmacsW32 on windows XP.